# Change PostgreSQL current database from java

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, jdbc-postgres

Is there any way to change postgreSQL current database from java application? 
or is there any equivalent for `\connect report` ?
I know i can do this by changing JDBC connection string, but is there any better alternative?

Comment: It is always better to have different datasources configured for different databases running in the same server. A connection at any point will point to only one database and you cannot change it. You can only open a new connection

Comment: maybe i should have described my solution, i need to list all databases to user and connect to one of them on his/her demand.

Comment: You can't CHANGE a connection. You can either OPEN or CLOSE it. If you want to work with a different databases, simple create a new connection to it. If you want don't want the previous connection, simply close it. Changing a data-source simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dave, So `let the user make the selection, and append it to the JDBC connection string`. If the user wants to change the connection, they will select which new database to connect to, right. So, close the previous connection, and create a new connection to the newer database.

Comment: @user2339071 thats what i am doing now, question raised when i tried to find simpler or maybe more elegant way. from what i learned from comments current way is the elegant one .

Comment: @dave LOL. Optimizations are hard. But, I would like to tell you that, this isn't an optimization problem. The language simply doesn't support it as of yet. Maybe Java 9. ;)